# How to insert if statement in sql query at vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net

How to insert if/else in the query?

This is my sqlcommand query :

```
 sqlcommand ("select Machine_Code,Machine_Name,Status from
 Machine_Master where '" & combolinecode.Text & "' = Line_Code" )
```

I wanna change the value of `Status` from *1 => active* and *0 => not active*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the ANSI standard `case` statement in almost all databases:

```
select Machine_Code, Machine_Name,
       (case when Status = 1 then 'active' else 'not active' end) as status
from Machine_Master
where '" & combolinecode.Text & "' = Line_Code";
```

I fear that if you are using VBA you might be using Access, which has its own way:

```
select Machine_Code, Machine_Name,
       iif(Status = 1, "active", "not active") as status
from Machine_Master
where '" & combolinecode.Text & "' = Line_Code";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` :

```sql
select Machine_Code
     , Machine_Name
     , (case when Status = 1 then 'active' else 'not active' end) as Status
from Machine_Master 
where '" & combolinecode.Text & "' = Line_Code
```